# How long before my red-eared slider lays eggs? Should I force her onto land?

Tags: breeding, turtles

I have 4 adult red-eared sliders, two male and two female.  One of my females is definitely carrying eggs.

They are in a wonderful outdoor habitat. We did all the research before we built it two years ago.  The reason we moved them from the tank they were in that was inside the house is because the female laid eggs in the water and they had gotten too big.

Last summer when we moved them outside, they hardly ever even basked on the ramp and never left the pond and walked around on land.  This year they bask on the ramp but still we have never seen them on land.

I know that the female has had eggs for at least 3 weeks now and am wondering if I should make her spend time on land in the enclosed habitat by fencing off an area inside the habitat to put her in so she will lay the eggs. Or will she eventually crawl out and nest on her own?

The mixture of soil to sand is exactly what it is supposed to be and is at least 13" deep throughout the habitat.  I used a rake and smoothed out the soil in the habitat so I will be able to tell if the turtles are getting out of the pond and walking around and am absolutely sure they haven't, so I know there isn't a nest that I'm just missing. I am also wondering if she does nest and the eggs hatch, will the babies dig to the surface on their own, or do I need to make sure I know where she nests so I can help?

Comment: You could look at this [question](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/18912/red-eared-slider-laying-eggs-into-the-water) for more details about the egg laying and the right place for it.