# How often do female redeared sliders need to lay eggs?

Tags: turtles

I've had my turtle for a very long time now and thought it was a male the whole time. I was told by a vet it was a male. Anyways about a month ago she laid eggs outside while I was cleaning her tank. So how often does this happen for her? I would like to be well informed to help her out. Please help. I've tried researching it but no solid answers yet. Thanks.

Comment: Old Related withut and answer (so not a duplicate) [How long before my redeared slider she lays eggs? Should I force her onto land?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/13487/how-long-before-my-redeared-slider-she-lays-eggs-should-i-force-her-onto-land)

Answer (score 1):

In nature the female RES turtle lays eggs once a year in springtime. It depends on the temperature over the year, so she could know the right time.

At home as pet it could be more or less than one time per year, because the seasons are not noticed in such a clear way like at the outside.

It depends on the temperature in the tank and the air around. Do you simulate seasons? Does she make a "sleeping winter time" for example in the fridge (to simulate the cold time on a lakes ground in winter)?

I assume she had no (simulated) seasons until now, so she never "want" to lay eggs until now.

If someone is thinking now something on the line "Oh, fine, so I avoid seasons and my turtle do not need to lay eggs" this is very dangerous. No seasons are no guarantee for no eggs. And if the turtle has no place to lay eggs they could stay in her and this will be toxic. Another point is the growing: if there is no cold time they eat and eat and grow faster than their shell could, so they get ill because of to less space for organs. (If one is frigthened about "winter in the fridge" first aid could be a long "autumn" in the tank with cool water, less sun-like-light-time and less feeding)